# How to bypass Safari Certificate Check with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, safari, ssl-certificate

I've been trying to run my Safari test on Windows and I just can't find a way around the security check "Safari can't identify the identity of this website". Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: Have you tried to manually accept the site's certificate/identity all the time? Will you always be running this test on the same computer? Is the certificate you are using self-signed?

Comment: I'll use RemoteWebDriver eventually, but for now I'm trying to start it from my local computer. I've installed the certificate and now it appear as "This certificate is OK.". But whenever I try to open the page I get this "Safari can't identify...."  with a button continue at the end.
So I'm looking for a hack maybe a JS that click on the continue button?

Comment: I don't have access to Safari right now, but see if that button can be clicked via Selenium. In Chrome and Firefox you can click buttons like that because they're standard HTML elements.

Comment: No it cannot be clicked with selenium... thats the main issue... It pops up in a windows like button, out of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- Manually accept the certificate.
- Click on the continue button with Selenium.
- Access this application like normal.

Comment: And you tried adding code that manually clicks the continue button? Can you post the HTML for the screen with the continue button on it?

Comment: there is no such option.... the continue button is part of windows window and it cannot be clicked with selenium code, since selenium reads only the htlm...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23647288/2241348  This looks like it might be a helpful post. Unfortunately it appears to be a limitation in Safari. Chrome and Firefox both have these screens appear as HTML, so you can get past them.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac you can start a timeout thread before driver.get() who's handler runs this applescript

```
tell application "System Events" 
    tell application process "Safari"
        click button "Continue" of group 2 of sheet 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```